# Standard c++ library headers not found by clang in FreeBSD

Tags: c++, clang, freebsd

I'm pretty new to c++, but writing, compiling and running simple c++ programs in Windows/Linux worked like a charm with some help from Google.

Trying to do the same in FreeBSD was however not that straight forward.

I'm currently trying to compile the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  std::cout << "Hello.\n";
}
```

with

```
cpp -v test.cpp -o test
```

Which results in

```
FreeBSD clang version 10.0.1 (git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git llvmorg-10.0.1-0-gef32c611aa2)
Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd12.2
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
 (in-process)
 "/usr/bin/cpp" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-freebsd12.2 -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=all -fno-rounding-math -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -fno-split-dwarf-inlining -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/clang/10.0.1 -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/v1 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/Administrator -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 120 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fobjc-runtime=gnustep -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o test -x c++ test.cpp
clang -cc1 version 10.0.1 based upon LLVM 10.0.1 default target x86_64-unknown-freebsd12.2
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/v1
 /usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Trying to locate the iostream file with

```
locate iostrem
```

gives no result.

FYI the OS is [TwinCAT/BSD for Industrial PCs](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/news/twincat-bsd/). Based on my resultless Googling efforts, I have a feelin that this is pretty relevant.

Is there anyone out there willing to give me a push in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: `cpp` is the C pre-processor. The correct front-end program is either `g++` or `clang++` (depending on what you have installed) and it will invoke the pre-processor with the correct settings, options and flags that's needed to find the C++ standard header files.

Comment: @Mat, thanks for the answer, but as far as I understand, FreeBSD replaced GCC with Clang around a decade ago.

Comment: Someprogrammerdude, thanks! Seems like I have some way to go to wrap my head around this. When I try to use g++, I get "-sh: g++: not found". Same with clang++. However, when I run "man g++", I'm getting the man page for clang.

Anyways, does this mean that I have to install either g++ or clang++?

Comment: Yes you need to install the compiler to be able to actually compile anything. :) The C pre-processor usually comes installed as standard as other systems might use it.

Comment: The C++ compiler is part of the base system. Use `c++` to invoke it.

Comment: `clang` and `clang++` are included in base FreeBSD (also usable as `cc` and `c++`). If for some reason you need a different compiler you can install it with `pkg`, for instance `pkg ins clang9`. Of course TwinCAT may have a different base and/or pkg system.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the C pre-processor on a C++ file. You need to use the C++ compiler with the -E flag if you want to only do pre-processing:

`c++ -E -o test test.cpp`

Remove the `-E` to compile to binary.

Also, I see you're using Clang 10.x and note that Clang 12 is showing different behavior. When I use

`cpp test.cpp -o test`

with Clang 12, it does recognize it as C++ and compile it, so it looks like behavior changed here. Still, the `c++` is the correct command to use for C++ files.